# Combining Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex

In Python, I want to combine

```
\s*\(r?["|\'](?P<pattern>[^\'"]+)["|\'],\s*["|\'](?P<view>[^\'"]+)["|\']\),
```

and

```
\s*url\(r?["|\'](?P<pattern>[^\'"]+)["|\'],\s*["|\'](?P<view>[^\'"]+)["|\']\),
```

I thought it was

```
\s*[url]?\(r?["|\'](?P<pattern>[^\'"]+)["|\'],\s*["|\'](?P<view>[^\'"]+)["|\']\),
```

Comment: What does "combining" two REs mean? Intersection? Union?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `[url]` which is `u` or `r` or `l`.

The solution is to use [noncapturing group](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups) `(?:url)` instead of `[url]`.

So, finally, you regex would look like:

```
\s*(?:url)?\(r?["|\'](?P<pattern>[^\'"]+)["|\'],\s*["|\'](?P<view>[^\'"]+)["|\']\),
```